# Access current matching react-router params from any Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have following setup (Just the important part):

App.jsx

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
        <div>
            <Navigation />

            <main>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/books" component={Books} />
            </main>
        </div>
    </ConnectedRouter>
</Provider>
```

Books.jsx

```
<Route exact path="/books" component={BookList} />
<Route exact path="/books/:bookId" component={BookDetails} />
```

Now I would like to get the `bookId` param inside the `<Navigation/>` Component. When I try `withRouter` I only get the `"/"` match so no `params`.
Also the redux store for the router only holds the full location path.

is it possible or do I have to work with the whole location path and parse it somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One important thing to note here is that with `withRouter` higher-order component you can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest `<Route>'s` match which in your case is the `/` for `ConnectedRouter`,

You can get the params using `matchPath` from react-router

```
const {hash} = window.location
const customMatch = matchPath(hash, {
    path: `/books/:bookId`,
    exact: true,
    strict: false
});
let bookId;
if (customMatch) {
    ({ bookId } = customMatch.params);
}
```

Comment: glad it helped you

Comment: btw. i replaced the hash with `this.props.routing.location` from my redux store because I didn't use the hash navigation.